# Django per-site cache not updating

Tags: django, caching

I have set up per-site cache using https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/cache/#the-per-site-cache documentation. But I see that the page cache doesn't update after the data change. Do I have to invalidate it manually somehow, or something is just improperly configured? UpdateCacheMiddleware goes first in my config and FetchFromCacheMiddleware goes last, as told in the doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are caching the entire site, the cache will not reflect the updated changes until the cache has expired.  If you are looking at making regular changes to dynamic pages, then you will want to go with a lower-level cache (per-view, template fragment, etc.) and implement cache invalidation.  This can get pretty complicated, so if you can get away with displaying stale data for a short period of time, you may find that saves you from getting a few headaches.

Comment: Can I cache something without a timeout? Docs also don't say about that. For example, if my cache key is some datetime instance and I don't need cache to invalidate.

Comment: I have not tried to implement a cache this way, but I do not believe that this is currently easily supported. It may be worth asking on a separate thread.  I was able to find this [ticket fix](https://github.com/django/django/commit/89955cc35f3636684ea6f2a6c9504b35a3050f0f), so there may be a solution available in the near future.